# (PHP) Accessing specific item in array with foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Here is the contents of `$result` array:

```
Array (
   [ts] => (somenumber)
   [_id] => (theid)
   [state] => sent
   [subject] => Test message
   [email] => (some email)
   [tags] => Array ( )
   [opens] => 0
   [clicks] => 0
   [smtp_events] => Array ( )
   [resends] => Array ( )
   [sender] => (some email)
   [template] => (some template)
   [opens_detail] => Array ( )
   [clicks_detail] => Array ( )
)
```

I want to access `[state] => sent` so that I can print the status, which is whether an email has been sent or not. Below is my code where I try to retrieve it with a `foreach` loop:

```
$result = $GLOBALS['mandrill']->messages->info($id);

// Get the status of the email
foreach ($result as $key => $message) {
    $status = $message['state'];
}
```

I get the error `Notice: Undefined index: state`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify:

```
$result = $GLOBALS['mandrill']->messages->info($id);

$status = $result['state'];
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `foreach` loop always remember `$key` is the content between the square bracket and `$message` is the value. Try this:

```
$result = $GLOBALS['mandrill']->messages->info($id);

// Get the status of the email
foreach ($result as $key => $message) {
    if($key == "status") $status = $message;
}
```

But `foreach` loop should not be used that way. You can simply use `$status = $result['status']` for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks bro appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access only state do this:

```
$result['state']; //This code finds the first array and the index of state

echo $result;
```

Comment: You can upvote answers if it work or accept them. @Spidey

Comment: Sorry there's a wait period couldn't do it yet haha, thanks for your help I appreciate it